# Teamcity Issue :Unable to add module to the current project as it is not of packaging type 'pom'

Tags: maven, teamcity, maven-archetype

I am trying to add `Maven` build step in `TeamCity` to generate `Maven` archetype.

```
mvn archetype:generate
```

This works fine in command prompt.

Unfortunately it throws below error in `TeamCity`:

> Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.1:generate
>   (default-cli) on project pso-jms-listener-archetype:
>   org.apache.maven.archetype.exception.InvalidPackaging: Unable to add
>   module to the current project as it is not of packaging type 'pom'

I created a new folder and tried executing it there, but still throws the same error

Any suggestions would help.

Answer (score 3):

You may already have a POM file in the directory where `mvn archetype:generate` is executed.

For [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-archetypes.html), archetype is

> a Maven project templating toolkit. An archetype is defined as an
> original pattern or model from which all other things of the same kind
> are made.

In short, you are creating a project (from a template) in an other project.
In your project folder, **delete the file `pom.xml` and use `mvn archetype:generate` again**.

Answer (score 0):

I have gone through this one and it took me a half hour to find the proper solution. Here I want to share for those who come later.

After executing `mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=yourGroupId -DartifactId=yourArtifactId` or just `mvn archetype:generate`, you should redirect to the parent project, and open the `pom.xml` file, and then add the `<packaging>pom</packaging>` to it. after that, you can add as many sub-modules as you want without any problems.